# Chrome Extension: How can I reload an extension when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I have made an chrome extension which highlights words on the content page and give information about those words in the pop-up window. The problem I'm facing is: when I switch to another tab, the information of words founded on a previous tab are still shown in the pop-up window on the new tab.

Is there a way I can reload the extension when switching tabs? or is there another solution for this problem?

PS Some webpages are not loading (properly) when the extension is active, I hope this problem will be solved as well when the extension is focusing on one tab only. But maybe the task I ask to run is to heavy (search for words in the innerText of the body.) Any suggestions how to solve this as well?

Comment: Sounds like [chrome.tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated).

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for your comment! The page reloads now when switching to another tab, so the pop-up only shows information of the current tab. 
When I browse to another url inside the same tab, the pop-up is still showing information about words founded on the previous url. Any idea how i could solve this problem?

Comment: Use a second listener: chrome.tabs.onUpdated